# how to hide an element at the end of javascript animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I know similar questions have been asked before, but the answers did not help me because they are too advanced for me and my simple animation. I am at the very beginning of javascript. On my website, I have the simple code for moving an element from one posotion to another. I would like to have it disappear when it reaches the final position, not fading out, just suddenly disappear. Should I do it with opacity change? How do I write it? My code is the following.

```
function myMove() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("animation");
    var pos = 100 ;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

    function frame() {
        if (pos == 380) {
            clearInterval(id);


        } else {
            pos++;
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
            elem.style.left = pos + 'px';

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hide it (using `elem.style.display = 'none'`) where you do `clearInterval(id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide an element simply set style.display to 'none'.

For example:

```
function myMove() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("animation");
    var pos = 100 ;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

    function frame() {
        if (pos == 380) {
            clearInterval(id);
            // this is the key line
            elem.style.display = 'none';

        } else {
            pos++;
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
            elem.style.left = pos + 'px';

        }
    }
```

Just as a heads up, using chained setTimeouts can be better than using setInterval in HTML animation. The reason being that if the animation (and/or other scripts on the page) takes longer than the interval the browser will become unresponsive. With a chain of setTimeouts, the clock doesn't start ticking until the end of the current frame.

For example, you could do:

```
function myMove() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("animation");
    var pos = 100 ;

    function frame() {
        if (pos == 380) {
            // this is the key line
            elem.style.display = 'none';

        } else {
            pos++;
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
            elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
            // set a timeout for 5 ms
            setTimeout(myMove, 5);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, display='none' did it for me.

Comment: Now that the animation itself works fine, there is one more thing i have not been able to figure out yet. I'll try to explain what I am doing: The animated element is an image of a dog cookie, which can basically be thrown into a dog's mouth, which is located at the end position of the animation.it looks fine on my screen, but as soon as I change the size of my browser window, the cookie flies by and does not end up in the dog's mouth. How would I include the image of the dog in the animation, so that the mouth would always be at the end position of the animated cookie? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Putting both the element that contains the dog and the one that contains the cookie in a div, and then giving those elements absolute positioning should eliminate and discrepancies caused by the size of the window.   OR  you could dynamically calculate the position of the dog and use that to determine the destination of the cookie.